# How do I make a reference to an appendix in LaTeX in a way that it shows a letter (e.g. appendix A) instead of a number (e.g. appendix 1)?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

How do I make a reference to an appendix in LaTeX in a way that it shows a letter (e.g. appendix A) instead of a number (e.g. appendix 1)? Here is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{appendices}

\chapter*{Appendix A}
\renewcommand\thechapter{A}
\cftaddtitleline{lot}{chapter}{Appendix A}{}
\label{appendix:a}


\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Using this in the text:

```
Appendix \ref{appendix:a}
```

leads to: Appendix 1

Comment: Could you please turn your code fragments into a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that inludes the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages.

Comment: Unfortunately, the title of your query does *not* speak for itself. Please tell us, at a bare minimum, which document class you employ, and please tell us whether you load the `appendix` and `tocloft` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neglected to say which class you are using. However the following (less any typos) works:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{An appendix} \label{app}
\lipsum[2] This is in appendix \ref{app}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Read the `appendix` package manual (`> texdoc appendix`) for more information about the package and its options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly, the problem remains...

Comment: @Deanerino Well, it worked for me. What did you do?